# How can I list all pods in a kubernetes cluster in Python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm trying to replicate the `kubectl get pods` command in Python3 using the [kubernetes python library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). Except, I'm working with a remote kubernetes cluster, NOT my localhost. The configuration host is a particular web address.

Here's what I tried:

```
    v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in ret.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

As recommended in the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). This however defaults to searching my localhost instead of the specific web address. I know I have access to this web address because the following runs totally 100% as expected:

```
import time
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
# Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
# Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'

# Defining host is optional and default to http://localhost
configuration.host = "THE WEB HOST I'M USING"

# Enter a context with an instance of the API kubernetes.client
with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = kubernetes.client.AdmissionregistrationApi(api_client)
    
    try:
        api_response = api_instance.get_api_group()
        pprint(api_response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling AdmissionregistrationApi->get_api_group: %s\n" % e)
```

What do you all think? How do I force it to check the pods of that host getting around the `localhost` default?

Comment: What do you mean by "web host". It needs a URL and other configuration to the Kubernetes API service. Normally this comes from your `.kube/config` file the same way as with kubectl and all other Kubernetes client tools.

Comment: Don't you need to pass `api_client` into `CoreV1Api`, like `kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(api_client)`?

Answer (score 5):

I know two solutions that may help in your case.
I will describe both of them and you may choose which one suits you best.

#### Using kubeconfig file

I recommend setting up a `kubeconfig` file which allows you to connect to a remote cluster.
You can find more information on how to configure it in the documentation: [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)

If you have a `kubeconfig` file configured, you can use the [load_kube_config()](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/master/config/kube_config.py#L782) function to load authentication and cluster information from your `kubeconfig` file.

I've created a simple `list_pods_1.py` script to illustrate how it may work:

```
$ cat list_pods_1.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
# Script name: list_pods_1.py
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config("/root/config")   # I'm using file named "config" in the "/root" directory

v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
    

$ ./list_pods_1.py 
Listing pods with their IPs:
10.32.0.2       kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-5k28b
10.32.0.3       kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-pfppk
10.156.15.210   kube-system     etcd-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-apiserver-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-controller-manager-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-proxy-gvxhq
10.156.15.211   kube-system     kube-proxy-tjxch
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-scheduler-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     weave-net-6xqlq
10.156.15.211   kube-system     weave-net-vjm7j
```

#### Using Bearer token

As described in this example - [remote_cluster.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6d4587e18064288d031ed9bbf5ab5b8245460b3c/examples/remote_cluster.py):

> Is it possible to communicate with a remote Kubernetes cluster from a server outside of the cluster without kube client installed on it.The communication is secured with the use of **Bearer token**.

You can see how to create and use the token in the [Accessing Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/) documentation.

I've created simple `list_pods_2.py` script (
based on the [remote_cluster.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6d4587e18064288d031ed9bbf5ab5b8245460b3c/examples/remote_cluster.py) script) to illustrate how it may work:

```
$ cat list_pods_2.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes import client, config
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

 # Define the barer token we are going to use to authenticate.
    # See here to create the token:
    # https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/
aToken = "<MY_TOKEN>"

    # Create a configuration object
aConfiguration = client.Configuration()

    # Specify the endpoint of your Kube cluster
aConfiguration.host = "https://<ENDPOINT_OF_MY_K8S_CLUSTER>"

    # Security part.
    # In this simple example we are not going to verify the SSL certificate of
    # the remote cluster (for simplicity reason)
aConfiguration.verify_ssl = False
    # Nevertheless if you want to do it you can with these 2 parameters
    # configuration.verify_ssl=True
    # ssl_ca_cert is the filepath to the file that contains the certificate.
    # configuration.ssl_ca_cert="certificate"

aConfiguration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + aToken}

    # Create a ApiClient with our config
aApiClient = client.ApiClient(aConfiguration)

    # Do calls
v1 = client.CoreV1Api(aApiClient)
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
            (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))



$ ./list_pods_2.py 
Listing pods with their IPs:
10.32.0.2       kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-5k28b
10.32.0.3       kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-pfppk
10.156.15.210   kube-system     etcd-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-apiserver-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-controller-manager-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-proxy-gvxhq
10.156.15.211   kube-system     kube-proxy-tjxch
10.156.15.210   kube-system     kube-scheduler-kmaster
10.156.15.210   kube-system     weave-net-6xqlq
10.156.15.211   kube-system     weave-net-vjm7j
```

**NOTE:** As an example, I am using a token for the default service account (you will probably want to use a different `ServiceAcccount`), but to work it properly this `ServiceAccount` needs appropriate permissions.
For example, you may add a `view` role to your `ServiceAccount` like this:

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding --serviceaccount=default:default --clusterrole=view default-sa-view-access
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/default-sa-view-access created
```

Comment: usually you would have the `config` file located under `~/.kube/`, in which case you would just do `config.load_kube_config()`, as the API defaults to `~/.kube/config`.

Comment: yes it's true, thanks for your note :)
I wanted to show that it is possible to configure this path.

Comment: matt_j, thank you so much for your help here. Looks like this has given me some good progress, but I'm running into a new issue. First of all, I've found I do in fact need to use SSL, as it will not let me go without. (so I uncommented the relevant lines and commented out the irrelevant). Hitting this error now: `urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Do you know how to overcome this?

`File "~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 381, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data)`using venv

Comment: verify* SSL, I mean to say above, as in I am required to use: `configuration.verify_ssl = True
    configuration.ssl_ca_cert = "certificate"`

Comment: You probably don't have the `ssl_ca_cert` in the appropriate location. How did you retrieve CA cert from your cluster. I prepared command to retrieve this cert from the `kubeconfig` file: `cat .kube/config | grep certificate-authority-data | cut -f2 -d: | xargs | base64 --decode` it maybe useful for you.